# asp.net Generating RSA public key pair without a key store

Tags: asp.net, security

I have to do some secure communication between a windows service and an asp.net website. In the asp.net website I am generating a key pair, sending my public key to my windows service and then receiving the encrypted message from my service and decrypting with asp.net.

The first problem is this.. The [user profile is not created in asp.net](http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2007/12/03/rsacryptoserviceprovider-fails-when-used-with-asp-net.aspx) so I must use RSAParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;.

This doesnt work in my hosting provider because I do not have access to my machine store.

I think my solution would be to generate the key pair in memory and never use the keystore, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/EZRSA.aspx Exerpt from the article:

"Help! What do we do?? A bit of Googling around, and a quick email to our (excellent) Web hosting providers Liquid Six, revealed that the reason for this lies deep inside the Windows crypt API, on which RSACryptoServiceProvider is based. Essentially, to allow scripts to load up their own private keys would compromise the security of the Windows key store, so all sensible Web hosting providers turn it off lest a rogue script steals / overwrites the hosting provider's own private keys. This strikes me as a major snafu in the Windows crypt API but there you go. I guess we're stuck with it.

Some more Googling turned up two essential resources: Chew Keong TAN's most excellent BigInteger class and some LGPL 'C' code to do the requisite calculations and PKCS#1 encapsulation from XySSL (originally written by Christopher Devine). These resources were particularly useful to me because (a) the ability to manipulate numbers with hundreds of digits is a specialist area, and (b) I hate ASN.1 (on which the PKCS#1 format is built). The calculations themselves are deceptively simple.

A day or two of stitching and patching later and EZRSA was born. EZRSA does pretty much everything that RSACryptoServiceProvider can do but entirely in managed code and without using the Windows crypt API. As a result, it will run anywhere, no matter what trust level your Web hosting provider imposes on you (which is what we needed)."

Hope it helps!